# How to lock out user in clearance after X failed login attempt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I'm using Rails 5 and clearance 1.16.0.

When user attempts loggin in for 4 times I would like to show them  a mesaage saying they are now locked

```
 if user.failed_attempts > 3 
     user.lock = true
     flash[:error] = "You have been locked out, please contact admin to unlock account"
 end
```

I know I can have a guard to check if user is locked and prevent them from logging in but how do I determine that the user has failed logging in? and increment the failed attempts counter using clearance.

Thanks

Comment: clearance doesn't support this, out of the box.  You'll have to implement it yourself.  Create a guard (add it to your initializer) and create a failure app method, have the failure app add 'attemps' to the user model.  have the failure app lock the model when attempt max is acheived

Comment: you can use devise gem instead of clearance

Comment: @trh I need the guard to be executed on failure which it does not?
It will only execute after user is logged in?

Comment: It seems like the only way to do it is to override behavoir which I did not want to do.
https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do it is to override behavoir which I did not want to do.

github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/742